# Display image in template with Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display images into articles in my blog project built with Django. Here is the related code:

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

urls.py (project):

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, 
                                verbose_name="Date de parution")
    image1 = models.ImageField()
    image2 = models.ImageField()
    image3 = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre
```

views.py:

```
def article(request, id, slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {'article': article})
```

post.html:

```
<img src="{{ article.image1.url }}"/>
<img src="{{ article.image2.url }}"/>
<img src="{{ article.image3.url }}"/>
```

However, it does not work. Images do not appear. Any suggestions ?

Comment: are you getting other fields in the template?? like title or author?

Comment: and can you inspect element and show what is being posted inside the src?

Comment: I do get other fields in the templates: title, author, text, they all work well. + the elements posted in the src is a simple .jpg image

Comment: can you show the src that is being posted?

Comment: I must mention that the <img src="[...]"/> are posted inside the text field.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Rainbow_Rose_%283366550029%29.jpg (I downloaded this image for testing purposes)

Comment: @JulienCorbin what happens if you try : `<img src="media/{{ article.image3.url }}"/>` or `<img src="/media/{{ article.image3.url }}"/>` ?

Comment: I added "upload_to ='media'" but it did not work. I also tried to ad "/media/" or "media/" in the src but it did not work either.

Comment: what exactly does the src of img contain? is it empty?<img src="what is in here when template is rendered?"/>

Comment: @Exprator does not work :Exception Type: PermissionError
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media'

Comment: when template is rendered, the img logo appears like if there was no image inside.

Comment: and there shouldn't be any forward slashes before or after media, it should simply be .join(BASE_DIR, 'media'). also you don't need to add upload_to('media') because the root is media. You are not advised to add images in media root, you should create an img folder inside media folder, and then add upload_to('img/') in your imagefield.

Comment: Ok now it almost works ! I removed the slashes around media in the Media root, changed the upload to 'img' and created a new folder. The images do show up when I add <img src="{{ article.image1.url}}"/> to the template. But now I'd like to add <img src="{{ article.image1.url}}"/> inside the textfield so that images show up inside the content of my article. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any forward slashes before or after media, it should simply be `.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`. also you don't need to add `upload_to('media')` because the root is media. You are not advised to add images in media root, you should create an img folder inside media folder, and then add `upload_to('img/')` in your imagefield.

Regarding inserting image preview inside a textbox/textfield, yes it is possible, but it should be a separate question, although I think there are many identical questions on it.